# How to display a binary image in HTML using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am getting image as binary on rest call using the code below.

```
vm.profilepicture = function(){

    profileService.bindimage('GET', 1).then(function(response){
        vm.image = response.data;

    });
}
```

And I have the tag:html for displaying the image as follows:

```
<div> 
   <img ng-src="data:image/JPEG;base64,{{vm.image}}">
</div>
```

But unfortunately its not displaying (only showing broken image). In developer console I can see the entire image what I stored in the db

[image]

On debugging i can see like

[image: this]

Can anyone help me how to display it properly in HTML?

Thanks ebk.

Comment: That file is binary, not base64.

Comment: @georgeawg op isn't trying to download the image, they are trying to create a dataURI for displaying it. The linked duplicate doesn't deal with that.

Comment: The OP states he is "getting image as binary on rest call". The console shows a corrupt string. If he gets the file as a blob, there is no need to convert it to base64. Simply set the src attribute to the blob.

Comment: @georgeawg how to get it the image as blob .i set the contentType='blob',but data is coming in same way as binary. in backend api do i need to change anything.

 response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");

Answer (score 0):

That is raw binary, the image tag doesn't understand that. You need to put it into a dataURI string which you already partially have. You just didn't convert your binary data to a base64 string, and you do this by using [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa) function

```
vm.image = btoa( response.data );
```

You can also try telling the request that you expect a `blob` response and with that you can create a object url for using as the image src

Change HTML to

```
<image ng-src="{{vm.image}}">
```

And JS to

```
//in your actual ajax call
$http.get({responseType: 'blob'})

//and in your response
vm.image = URL.createObjectURL( response.data );
```

Comment: after using btoa i am getting this error-

Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.

Comment: @ebk in that case try the other method in the edit. You will need to change your ajax call to request the response be in a Blob format instead of raw binary and use createObjectURL to get a src url.

Comment: @ Patrick Evans i think raw data can't be pass to createObjectURL() as like this createObjectURL( response.data ); so i explicitly convert to blob and pass to createObjectURL(blob).so now i am getting one image url as "blob:http://localhost:3000/331b573e-d601-45b5-ab5c-de24091d0da9".but i am unlucky the problem is still existing .i copied the url and paste it in new tab that time i am getting an image with black background .